# How does this seemingly random bit of string solve the TwoSum problem?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, sum

From LeetCode, the definition of the "Two Sum Problem" is:

> Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices
> of the two numbers such that they add up to target.
>
> You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and
> you may not use the same element twice.
>
> You can return the answer in any order.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> **nums** = [2,7,11,15]
>
> **target** = 9
>
> **Output**: [0,1]

The current solution on LeetCode with the fastest runtime on Python is the following:

```
class Solution(object):
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        from zlib import decompress
        from base64 import b64decode
        open('user.out', 'wb').write(decompress(b64decode("eJyLNtRRMIjlijbSUTAEUggekqAxiqCJjoIRhgZjFEGESgMMJVDtphDKGK7SGKFy2FKwAAFyTRGilkCgowAkLIAcMx0IaQmSN9IxAqsz0zE0B9IGOsDABQCpFVmV"))),exit(0)
```

From my perspective, I have no idea how this code would be generated. It seems like they taking an advantage of a vulnerability in the interpreter, but even that isn't clear.

How exactly does this script run and how does it perform the actions noted above in the problem description?

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. It just creates a file with static contents unrelated to `nums` and `target`.

Comment: Run it and look at the file `user.out`.

Comment: I would guess that they somehow got knowledge of the test-cases that are used by the Leetcode server to judge a program, and they hardcoded the answers for these test-cases, like a student who got a look at the exam paper beforehand and memorised all the answers and can give the answers to all exam questions without even reading the questions.

Comment: I guess it takes advantage of a vulnerability in LeetCode. It writes the correct results of all the test cases in a file which is probably used by LeetCode to temporarily store the regular output of the script.

Comment: Even if that's what this is doing, I don't see how it can actually work. I assume the LeetCode submission tool calls `Solution().twoSum()` separately for each test case, not once for everything. This will duplicate all the output for each test case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base64 allows to encode binary data as text, which then is decompressed

```
from zlib import decompress
from base64 import b64decode
print(decompress(b64decode("eJyLNtRRMIjlijbSUTAEUggekqAxiqCJjoIRhgZjFEGESgMMJVDtphDKGK7SGKFy2FKwAAFyTRGilkCgowAkLIAcMx0IaQmSN9IxAqsz0zE0B9IGOsDABQCpFVmV")))
```

gives output

```
b'[1, 0]\n[2, 1]\n[1, 0]\n[2, 0]\n[2, 1]\n[3, 0]\n[2, 0]\n[4, 2]\n[2, 1]\n[1, 0]\n[3, 2]\n[2, 1]\n[2, 0]\n[4, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[3, 2]\n[4, 2]\n[5, 2]\n[3, 0]\n[4, 3]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 0]\n[4, 0]\n[11, 5]\n[1, 0]\n[9999, 9998]\n[6,8]\n[6,9]\n[12,25]\n[16,17]\n[0,1]\n'
```

so author just stored expected output and is then writing it to `user.out` which I presume is then tested by judge.

Comment: This was my initial guess as well, but I had also assumed that the test-cases were randomized from a large pool to prevent something like this. I'm wondering if the submitter continually tried a static response until it eventually succeeded?